# How to rename dataframes in list based on values in their columns with lapply

Tags: r, function, lapply, assign

I have a list of dataframes `x` with column `V1` that says the country and `V2` that says the year.

The names of the dataframes are y1, y2, y3 and so on. I want to rename them so that they show the country and year (ALBANIA1993, JAPAN2002, etc.). The following code works individually on the dataframes:

```
y1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("ALBANIA", "ALBANIA", "ALBANIA"), c(1999, 1999, 1999)))
y2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("JAPAN", "JAPAN", "JAPAN"), c(2002, 2002, 2002)))
x <- list(y1, y2)

assign(as.character(with(y1, paste0(y1$V1[1], y1$V2[1]))), y1)
assign(as.character(with(y2, paste0(y2$V1[1], y2$V2[1]))), y2)
```

I am trying to use `lapply` to apply this to all dataframes from list `x` at once.

Here's the code:

```
x <- list(y1, y2)
x <- lapply(x, function(y) assign(as.character(with(y, paste0(y$V1[1], y$V2[1]))), y))
```

As you can see, it is the same code as before, but inside `lapply`. For some reason, the dataframes in `x` don't get renamed and there's no error shown.

Really appreciate the help! I'll edit in case you want more info.

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `assign` you could just reassign the names with `names`:

```
x1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("ALBANIA", "ALBANIA", "ALBANIA"), c(1999, 1999, 1999)))

x2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("JAPAN", "JAPAN", "JAPAN"), c(2002, 2002, 2002)))
x <- list(x1, x2)

theRenamer = function(input.list, ...){
  newNames = lapply(input.list,function(y) as.character(with(y, paste0(y[1,1], y[1,2])))) # get the names you want to assign
  names(input.list) = as.character(newNames) # assign them with "names"
  return(input.list) # return the list
}
x = theRenamer(x)
```

The function could likely be simplified.

**EDIT:**

Yup, here's a one-liner:

```
names(x) = as.character(lapply(
    x,function(y) as.character(with(y, paste0(y[1,1], y[1,2])))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `setNames`

```
x <- lapply(x, function(x) setNames(x,nm=c(as.character(x$V1[1]),as.character(x$V2[1]))))
```

If you read `y1` using `stringsAsFactor=FALSE` then you can remove `as.character`